# How can I parse an ISO 8601 date string in Swift 5.3?

Tags: swift, macos, nsdateformatter

I've tried using `ISO8601DateFormatter`, but that doesn't seem to be working as expected:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.date(from: "2020-11-16T12:31:43Z") // returns nil
```

In addition to that, formatting a `Date` as an ISO 8601 string and parsing it back doesn't seem to work:

```
formatter.date(from: formatter.string(from: Date())) // returns nil
```

This is using the Swift REPL — `Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)` on macOS 10.15.6.

I could use `DateFormatter` with a handwritten format, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.
Is there a standard way to parse ISO 8601 strings? And how come formatting a string and parsing it back doesn't work?

EDIT: For clarity, here is my complete REPL session with the exact code that I entered, and with unchanged output.

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
  baseNSFormatter@0 = {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = NSISO8601DateFormatter
    }
  }
  _formatter = {}
  _timeZone = "GMT"
  _formatOptions = 1907
}
  3> formatter.formatOptions = .withInternetDateTime
  4> formatter.date(from: "2020-11-16T12:31:43Z")
$R0: Date? = nil
  5> formatter.date(from: formatter.string(from: Date()))
$R1: Date? = nil
```

I've also tried `formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]` and `formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withInternetDateTime)` without success.

Comment: You need to tell the formatter which format the string is, `formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that, but it doesn't seem to affect the outcome. `formatter.date` is still returning `nil` for the above two test cases.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue using Swift REPL but the exact code works fine in a playground so the issue isn't with your code it seems but with Swift REPL

Comment: You're right, this seems to work as expected in my compiled app. Still not sure why the REPL behaves this way.